# Scala CSV parsing without regex

Tags: string, scala, csv, parsing

I am writing a small CSV parser for a project in scala. The stipulations on the project do not allow the use of regex or non-official external libraries.

I have most of it working, however there is one case that is giving me trouble and that is when the data within the CSV cell contains a comma.

I am parsing a dataset that is stored in a CSV. The parsing function takes an array of strings as its only argument
this Array represents taking a row from the CSV and invoking `split(",")`.
The data that is stored in the CSV is formatted such that if there is a comma within the data then the entire data cell is enclosed in quotes `("")`.
The issue is that when `split(",")` is invoked it splits in the middle of the quoted cell because it doesnt know to ignore that comma.
I need a way to ignore that comma,essentially "fixing" the paramater array

### example

say a line inside the CSV looks as such before  any splitting occurs.

`"Hello, everyone", green, blue, 5, 3.2`

after `split(",")` we end up with

`|"hello|everyone"|green|blue|5|3.2|    // (Array length 6)`

where I need it to be

`|"hello, everyone"|green|blue|5|3.2|   //( Array length 5)`

Is there an obvious method for doing this that I am missing?

Comment: @jwvh I added a more extensive example that should help clarify

Comment: @jwvh do you know how CSV files work? `green` and `blue` do not have commas within their data, `hello, everyone` does, so it is surrounded by quotes `("")`. I need to skip over the comma inside the quotes when using the `split(",")` method on the line `"Hello, everyone", green, blue`.

Comment: for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines().drop(1)) {
          val column = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1).map(_.trim)
}

Comment: The above code is for the condition when your csv fie contains header.
That is why drop(1) used.
Source is scala.io.Source and file is java.io

Comment: @md samual I said that I can’t use regex

Answer (score 1):

```
""""Hello, everyone",green,blue,5,3.2"""  //raw CSV
  .split(",")                             //split at all commas  
  .foldRight((List[String](), false)){    //recombine quoted strings
    case (str,(lst, false))  => (str :: lst,      str.count(_ == '"')%2 > 0)
    case (str,(hd::tl,true)) => (s"$str,$hd"::tl, str.count(_ == '"')%2 < 1)
  }._1
  .mkString("|") //reformat just to demonstrate success
//res0: String = "Hello, everyone"|green|blue|5|3.2
```

Note: This assumes that quote marks, `"`, come in pairs. If the raw CSV data has a single quote mark, or any odd number of them, then the results are likely incorrect.